# Using Ansible to remove multiple Unix accounts

Tags: automation, ansible, user-accounts, rhel6

I have written the below `ansible` code for removal of `Unix` user accounts.

```
  - hosts: dev
    vars:
    username: 'testuser'
    become: true
    tasks:
    - name: Remove User
      user:
       name: '{{ username }}'
       state: absent
       remove: yes
```

This works fine for a single user. However if I want to remove multiple users at the same time , do I need to create separate variable for each of the user to be deleted and a separate `user` resource to remove this user. In that case if there are mulitple users the code will become too long. ANy suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of users to be deleted *`user_names`*. Then iterate the list by [*loop*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

```yaml
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  vars:
    user_names:
      - testuser1
      - testuser2
      - testuser3
  tasks:
    - name: Remove Users
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
        remove: true
      loop: "{{ user_names }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you follow below steps.
1. Create vars.yaml file and add list of users in it

```
---

user_name:
      - 'testuser1'
      - 'testuser2'
      - 'testuser3'
      - 'testuser4'
```

2. Write playbook in as below. Just removed var section in it. lets name this playbook as "test_users.yaml"

```
  - hosts: dev
    become: true
    tasks:
    - name: Remove User
      user:
       name: '{{ username }}'
       state: absent
       remove: yes
```

3. Run Playbook with following commands.

   $ ansible-playbook  test_users.yaml -e @vars.yml

Comment: If you have user_name in vars.yml then it should be  name" '{{user_name }}'  in test_users.yaml